# Member variable declared in .m file keeps its value between instances of the class

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, variable-declaration

I have the follow implementation file for `MyClass`:

```
BOOL myBool;

@implementation MyClass

// ...

- (void) someMethod {
    myBool = YES;
}

@end
```

It seems like `myBool` will be `YES` for every instance of `MyClass` after `someMethod` is called on just one instance of `MyClass`. However if I define `myBool` like this it has a unique value for each instance of `MyClass`:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL myBool;
@end
```

What is the difference between the above two "member variable" syntaxes?

Comment: Objective-C does not have "member variables".  It has "instance variables".   Pretty close to the same thing, but using precise vocabulary makes it easier to discuss such things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in 1st case it is not member variable, it is global variable so it naturally persists its value between multiple instances of your class.

If you want to declare ivar in class implementation file you can do the following:

```
@implementation MyClass{
   BOOL myBool;
}
...
```